# iScroll in a Right-to-Left website

Tags: javascript, jquery, right-to-left, iscroll

I want to use `iScroll 4` in a **Right-to-Left** website.
I defined to my list items:

```
direction: rtl
float: right
```

Also, at the beginning I call the function `scrollToElement` so the page opens the first item.

The problem that remains for me is that when the page scrolls to a particular item - it is scrolling so that its **left edge** aligned to the **left edge of the page**, and what I need is - its **right edge** to be aligned to the **right edge of the page**.

Is it possible to get it?

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BnCnT/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my colleagues found the answer.

In the iScroll js file, you should replace this line:

```
pos.left = pos.left > 0 ? 0 : pos.left < that.maxScrollX ? that.maxScrollX : pos.left;
```

with:

```
pos.left = pos.left - el.clientWidth + that.wrapperW;
```

.